# Resources not found exception R.string

Tags: android, string, resources

i need to add string (from resource) to Database

```
 <string name="variable_name">AAAAA</string>

Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.variable_name)
```

I tried to: -

1. clean project
2. fix Android properties
3. restart Eclipse

In R file variable_name exist. Sorry for my english

Comment: Did you import "<project name>.R" instead of android.R?

Comment: You can try to manually delete contents of bin and gen directories, as sometimes eclipse will ignore them when you clean project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are not importing `android.R.java` and

You should get like this

```
String str=getResources().getString(R.string.variable_name);
```

Comment: getResourse() - no found this method, i sure that i doesn't import android.R.java , variable variable_name exist in R file

Comment: @KostyaKhuta Are you calling this inside of `onCreate()` of your Activity? and post your code

Comment: Mo, from other class
public class DataBase {
/////
addExercise(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.squatting).toString(), "", "", 3, R.drawable.legs_squatting_a, db);
}

Comment: @KostyaKhuta You should call it in the activity scope, if your other class have `context`, then call it like this `context.getResources().getString(R.string.variable_name);`

Comment: @KostyaKhuta good to know ...Mark this as answer by checking the right mark beside the answer